# How to convert a column value to row header and have another column value as its value in SQL oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data like this below in a table

```
ID  NAME    TYP  VALUE
== ======  ====== =======
1   JON      B    123
1   JON      C    456
1   JON      D    789
1   JON      B    545
1   JON      C    295
```

and need a output like

```
ID  NAME    B     C       D
== ====== ====== ====== ======
1   JON     123   456     789
1   JON     54    295    NULL
```

But getting the output as

```
ID   NAME    B    C    D
== ======= ====  ===   ===
1   JON    123  NULL  NULL      
1   JON   NULL   456  NULL  
1   JON   NULL   NULL  789
1   JON   545   NULL   NULL 
1   JON  NULL   295    NULL
```

SQL used below and when I run this SQL I am getting NULL rows extra

```
select ID, name ,case when typ ='B' then value end B,case when typ ='C' then value end  C,case when typ ='D' then value end D from table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation . . . with `row_number()`:

```
select ID, name,
       max(case when typ = 'B' then value end) as B,
       max(case when typ = 'C' then value end) as C,
       max(case when typ = 'D' then value end) as D
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id, name, type order by value desc) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
group by id, name, seqnum
```

Comment: That looks like a typo bob Jarvis